# How to Fix forcerecaptchaflow from phoneauthoptions = false, forcerecaptchaflow from firebasesettings = false

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform

i was using firebase phone authentication before but after upgrade to paid plan it is showing this error
forcerecaptchaflow from phoneauthoptions = false, forcerecaptchaflow from firebasesettings = false

Can someone help with a solution. below is a screen shot of my code

> 

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:my_oga_rider/repo/user_repo.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import '../../services/views/welcome_screen/welcome_screen.dart';
import '../services/model/usermodel.dart';
import '../services/views/Car_Registration/verification_pending.dart';
import '../services/views/Login_Screen/login_screen.dart';
import '../services/views/Main_Screen/main_screen.dart';
import '../services/views/SignUp_Screen/signup_screen.dart';
import 'exceptions.dart';

class AuthenticationRepository extends GetxController {
  static AuthenticationRepository get instance => Get.find();

  //Variables
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  var verificationId = "".obs;
  dynamic credentials;
  final _userRepo = Get.put(UserRepository());

  UserModel? _userModel;


// Functions

  void phoneAuthentication(String phoneNo) async {
    await _auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: phoneNo,
      verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
        credentials = credential;
      },
      codeSent: (verificationId, resendToken) {
        log('Code sent');
        this.verificationId.value = verificationId;
      },
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (verificationId) {
        this.verificationId.value = verificationId;
      },
      verificationFailed: (e) {
        if (e.code == "invalid-phone-number") {
          Get.snackbar('Error', 'Provided phone number is not valid.');
        } else {
          Get.snackbar('Error', 'Something went wrong. Try again.');
        }
      },
    );
  }

  verifyOtp(String otpNumber) async {
    Get.snackbar(
        "Error", "OTP Verification Called", snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
        backgroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.1),
        colorText: Colors.green
    );
    PhoneAuthCredential userCredential =
    PhoneAuthProvider.credential(verificationId: verificationId.value, smsCode: otpNumber);
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(userCredential).then((value) async {
      final firebaseUser = value;
      if(firebaseUser.user != null){
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString("CUserID", firebaseUser.user!.uid);
      }
    }).catchError((e) {
      Get.snackbar(
          "Error", e.toString(), snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.1),
          colorText: Colors.green
      );
    });
  }

  Future<bool> verifyOTP(String otp) async {
    var credentials = await _auth.signInWithCredential(
        PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
            verificationId: verificationId.value, smsCode: otp));
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setString("CUserID", credentials.user!.uid);
    return credentials.user != null ? true : false;
  }

  Future<void> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final firebaseUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      if(firebaseUser.user != null){
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString("UserID", firebaseUser.user!.uid);
        prefs.setString("UserEmail", firebaseUser.user!.email!);
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      final ex = SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure.code(e.code);
      Get.snackbar(
          ex.toString(), ex.message, snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          colorText: Colors.red
      );
      throw ex;
    } catch (_) {
      const ex = SignUpWithEmailAndPasswordFailure();
      Get.snackbar(
          ex.toString(), ex.message, snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          colorText: Colors.red
      );
      throw ex;
    }
  }

  Future<void> loginUserWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password) async {
    try {
      final firebaseUser = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      if(firebaseUser.user != null){
        SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
        prefs.setString("UserID", firebaseUser.user!.uid);
        prefs.setString("UserEmail", firebaseUser.user!.email!);
        checkVerification();
      }
      else {
        Get.to(() => const LoginScreen());
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      Get.snackbar(
          "Error", e.toString(), snackPosition: SnackPosition.BOTTOM,
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
          colorText: Colors.red
      );
    }
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.remove("UserID");
    prefs.remove("UserEmail");
    Get.offAll(() => const WelcomeScreen());
  }

  Future<bool> uploadCarEntry(Map<String,dynamic> carData)async{
    bool isUploaded = false;

    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final userID = prefs.getString("UserID")!;

    await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Drivers').doc(userID).set(carData,SetOptions(merge: true));

    isUploaded = true;

    return isUploaded;
  }

  String? docId;
  var myUserDetail = UserModel().obs;

  checkVerification() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final userID = prefs.getString("UserID")!;
    final userEmail = prefs.getString("UserEmail");

    _userRepo.getUserById(userID).then((value) => {
      _userModel = value
    });
    var myInt = int.tryParse(_userModel!.isVerified!);
    if(myInt == 0){
      await _auth.signOut();
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.remove("UserID");
      prefs.remove("UserEmail");
      Get.offAll(const VerificaitonPendingScreen());
    }
    else if(myInt == 1) {
      Get.snackbar("Welcome", "Logged In Successful",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
          backgroundColor: Colors.green.withOpacity(0.1),
          colorText: Colors.green);
      Get.offAll(() => MainScreen());
    }
    else{
      Get.snackbar("Error", "Couldn't Verify your account, contact support!",
          snackPosition: SnackPosition.TOP,
          backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent.withOpacity(0.1),
          colorText: Colors.red);
      await _auth.signOut();
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      prefs.remove("UserID");
      prefs.remove("UserEmail");
      Get.offAll(const WelcomeScreen());
    }
  }

}
```

i have try adding SHA1 and SHA256 key and it still not working

i think Android Deveice Verification API from google is depreciated and maybe it is the cause? just saying

Comment: having same issue, Have you tried adding the SHA1 and SHA256 to the App attest ? and also added the playstore APP SIGNING SHA 256 key to firebase console? and also updated the google-service.json after updating the SHA keys?

Comment: Also facing such issue, did you found the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Updated the `firebase_auth` to a higher version and it worked

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the latest upgrade Auth OTP not working on a virtual device try on a real device with an active sim card.

Comment: I'm getting this issue at real device.